# ZF2 Routing structure for multiple modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am building a ZF2 application called "EcommerceUI". This application, tries to make use of multiple sub modules like, "LogsUI", "ReportsUI" etc.. My structure is as under:

```
ecommerce-ui
 -->config
 -->data
 -->module
     -->EcommerceUI
     -->LogsUI
     -->ReportsUI
 -->public
    -->js
    -->css
    -->images
    -->.htaccess
    -->index.php
 -->vendor
     -->ThirdPartyModule1
     -->ThirdPartyModule2
```

How do I create the routing such that:

```
http://ecommerceui  -> goes to ecommerceui/ecommerceui/index

http://ecommerceui/logsui -> goes to ecommerceui/logs/index
```

Also, how can I make each module share JS, CSS, Images in the public folder?

Comment: thats how ZF2 works. It is default. Don't get your question.

Comment: each module has access to the whole public folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your routes set up correctly in your module.config.php file.

This page in the ZF2 User Guide guides you through the process of setting up routes: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

In ecommerce-ui/module/LogsUI/config/module.config.php the routes should be something like this:

```
<?php
 return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'LogsUI\Controller\LogsUI' => 'LogsUI\Controller\LogsUIController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'logsui' => array(
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'LogsUI\Controller\LogsUI',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),

'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'logsui' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
);
```

Comment: hmm..that's what i need help with. Can you provide a proper example for my scenario above?

Comment: edited my initial reply to provide example. I'd strongly suggest that you spend an evening following the ZF2 tutorial at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/overview.html as this will give you a far better understanding of what is required.